# Why can't I send emails with my domain name emails without deliverability issues?

Tags: email, authentication, dkim, email-headers, dmarc

I have separate my website and email hosting. I use yandex smail service for email hosting. Everytime I send and email to an address, I get no dkim authentication issue even though, I have configured spf, dkim and dmarc in my dns zone.

For example, if I send someone an email and they have a gmail account, they will receive my email with a question mark instead of an unknown avatar and when they hover the avatar it will say: "Gmail couldn't verify that [my domain] actually sent this message (and not a spammer). "

Comment: Could you share more information on this? Share the header details of received email on Gmail. Otherwise it will be very difficult to understand the problem here.

Comment: I can't share emails in public or the crawler bots will spam them.

Comment: @architjn Information vital to answering the question should not be shared privately. Duff, how about creating a throw-away email adress to use here?

Comment: @DuffDuffourDamus Have you tried contacting yandex support?

Comment: @DuffDuffourDamus you can also share dmarc reports you must be receiving. Sharing that in public is not a problem.

Comment: @ModusTollens I did

Comment: @ModusTollens I wasn't able to contact them. architjn I didn't receive any report.

Comment: @DuffDuffourDamus In your DMARC record make sure you have your email id in `rua` tag. You will start to receive reports. I am pretty sure I can resolve it but with some kind of reports and information only.

Comment: @architjn The DKIM issue happens because of a bug on the mail service that I use and they have fixed it. Thank you for everything